# monit sending multiple duplicate emails

Tags: monit

set alert bob123@test.com

The problem is when the filesystem goes down multiple duplicate emails are sent that spam my inbox.  Is there a way to only send 1 email when the filesystem goes down?

Comment: Hello, is this the only "set alert" statement in your configuration, check for a additional "set alert ... reminder ...". From my point Monit (5.19.0, 5.29.0, 5.31.0) works like expected. I got two alerts, for the "Status failed" and "Status succeeded".

A question only, sorry.